# Is it possible to mount a RAID 1 software/mdadm member raw?

Tags: software-raid, raid1

I am wondering if a software member can be mounted directly. Is the software raid this transparent? I think this would be a nice thing to know just in case the RAID management fails for some reason?

If this is the case, does this apply to hardware RAID 1 systems?

Answer (score 2):

For mdadm RAID 1, it's possible. However, doing so (bypassing the RAID layer in any way) would put the drives out of sync, which in turn will cause corruption. So it's best to mount read-only.

Determine the data offset:

```
# mdadm --examine /dev/sda2
[...]
     Raid Level : raid1
[...]
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
[...]
```

In this case it's 2048 sectors.

Create a (preferably read-only) loop device with that offset:

```
# losetup --find --show --offset=$((2048*512)) /dev/sda2
/dev/loop3
```

Mount it:

```
# mount -o ro /dev/loop3 /mnt/somewhere
```

The loop device creation and mount can also be expressed in one command:

```
# mount -o ro,loop,offset=$((2048*512)) /dev/sda2 /mnt/somewhere
```

One of the downsides of read-only mounting is that the mount might fail if the filesystem is in an unclean state, and can't be repaired due to read-onlyness. In this case it's possible to put [a copy-on-write overlay](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Recovering_a_failed_software_RAID#Making_the_harddisks_read-only_using_an_overlay_file) on top of the loop device.

Please note, if you don't do this strictly read-only, and bypass the RAID layer, the RAID is no longer in sync and corruption issues will follow if you don't force the RAID to resync/repair itself afterwards.

---

For hardware and other types of RAID, it depends on the format. A lot of RAID have metadata at the end, so you can do the same steps with offset 0. Otherwise you have to determine the data offset somehow.

If there is no filesystem on the RAID (cryptsetup, LVM, ...) you have to open those layers before the mount step. If the RAID device is partitioned, loop devices support partitions (`losetup --partscan` then e.g. `/dev/loop3p1`).